# Adding a const to a class component to show data from Contentful CMS in a Gatsby site

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, contentful

[I am attaching a link to an image showing query in GraphQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRjac.png)I have a problem starting to show content from Contentful in my Gatsby site. I have established what query will access a simple text field data. I am confused how to add this data to a class component that builds my page. I think I have a proper code below in the JSX in return part, but I do not know how to pass the data to the component.

Below is my code that is grabbing the data from CMS:

```
const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
        allContentfulHomepage{
          edges {
            node {
              section1Title
            }
          }

        }
      }
  `)
```

I want to add it to a stateful component like this:

```
class IndexPage extends React.Component { }
```

I think my problem lies with the passing of data, but below additionally I show how I return it:

```
<div className = "section-text small-text" > {
    data.allContentfulHomepage.edges.map((edge) => {
        return ( 
            <h2> {
                edge.node.section1Title
            } 
            </h2>
        )
    })
} 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Are you seeing any errors? Have you read this already? https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/use-static-query/

Comment: Hi! Thanks, I will read this now. Basically I have a Onepage with several fields editable through Contentful, so it's super simple. Still I need to understand the use of static queries well. Yes I have errors. What I need further down the road is how to query several times on one page (as it is a onepage). For the moment I just want to display one simple title.

Comment: `Because of how queries currently work in Gatsby, we support only a single instance of useStaticQuery in a file`. Based on your comment, i think this could be a problem for you

Comment: do you already understand the 12 MAIN CONCEPTS from the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html)? if not, see my answer. if yes, see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi Aprillion, thank you, I will now re-read the documentation.

Comment: @ksav yes, I read it, that there can be one instance of useStaticQuery. Somehow I will need to query once for several input CMS fields.

Comment: Can you use a page query? https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/page-query/